# Overriding/mocking a hardcoded value in python unittest/pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am not able to override a hardcoded path value while mocking a method. I am used to mocking the return value of a method itself, but if any method is using a variable/hardcoded path, how can I override it or mock it?

Below is the actual method under call file:

```
def call_me(args):
    
    path='cloud/location/folder/file.csv'
    upload('path')
    print(path)
```

Test class is below:

```
import call  #importing the code file

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_call_me(self):
        args = -user 1233 -pwd 344'
        call_me(args)
```

how can I mock/override the path to a local path and use instead of mocking the upload method?

Comment: The best you can do is patch `upload` with a function that calls the real `upload` function with your own argument.

Comment: so there is no way to mock/patch/override any hardcoded value ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Patching `upload` is different because it's a free variable: you actually have access to the scope where the name is actually defined (in this case, the module-global scope). There's no way to access the scope of a function in the same way.

Comment: Local variables are set each time the function is executed, so there is just no point in time where you can patch them.